# python dict is unhashable

Tags: python, dictionary

New python learner here and i encountered a problem where it says my dict is unhashable. I searched up this on stack overflow for other answers but i couldn't understand them well. Does any one have a explanation for what is unhashable that is easy to understand? Also here is the part of my code where things went wrong

```
for name1, itemdescription1 in thisitem.items():
    if rooms[currentroom-1][currentroom]["items"][name1][itemdescription1] == "yes": # if player already got this item
        print ("You didn't find anything")
```

on the middle line of the code above it says TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict' 
And here is my code for the

```
rooms = [

    {1 : {
        "name" : "hall",
        "east" : 2,
        "south" : 3,
        "description" : "An empty hallway, nothing of use here. ",
        "items" : {"torch" : {"a dim torch " : "no"}}
    }}, 
    {2 : {
        "name" : "kitchen",
        "west" : 1,
        "east" : 4,
        "south" : 6,
        "description" : "An odd smell reeks from the kitchen. What could it be? ",
        "items" : {"meat" : {"a piece of vile meat " : "no"}}
    }},
    {3 : {
        "name" : "bedroom",
        "north" : 1,
        "east" : 6,
        "description" : "A overwelmingly big room containing two gigantic beds, hmmm... ",
        "items" : {"key" : {"a silver key " : "no"}}
    }},
    {4 : {
        "name" : "diningroom",
        "west" : 2,
        "south" : 5,
        "description" : "A large room with tables and chairs, nothing special. ",
        "items" : {"plate" : {"a white plate " : "no"}}
    }},

    {5 : {
        "name" : "bathroom",
        "north" : 4,
        "west" : 6,
        "description" : "A creepy shadow lays in the bathtub, better go somewhere else. ",
        "items" : {"shampoo" : {"a bottle of shampoo " : "no"}}
    }},
    {6 : {
        "name" : "garage",
        "north" : 2,
        "west" : 3,
        "east" : 5,
        "description" : "It reeks of blood here. You wonder why. ",
        "items" : {"bolts" : {"some rusted iron bolts " : "no"}} 
}}
]
```

Comment: What are the values in `thisitem.items()`?

Comment: Can you please create a [Minimum, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your issue? Right now its difficult to say what the issue is, as all of the applicable code is not present.

Comment: Print `name1` and `itemdescription1`. Atleast one of them is of type `dict` and you are trying to use it as key in a dict, hence the error.

Comment: short question: in a dict like {a: b}, which one is the key? and what do you call the other one? thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Answer To the Question *As Stated*

Any object that does not implement the `__hash__()` and `__eq()__` magic methods in its class definition is unhashable.

A hashable object is something that can be mapped to a unique identifying value - think of a function that can take your object and return a corresponding unique number, and you have the right idea. They are the buildings blocks of hashtables and dictionaries, which work on the premise that this unique value (the hash) of a key is meant to refer to the block of memory where the value is stored - that way you can look up the value of a key very, very quickly (constant time, in fact).

In practice, this unhashability condition usually means that *mutable objects* - objects whose contents can be changed in memory, rather than by returning a new modified object - are unhashable.

Lists and dictionaries are unhashable. Tuples, strings and integers - all immutable objects - are hashable.

It *is* possible to extend lists and dictionaries in such a way that they are hashable. However, there are only a few niche use cases that can justify the use of hashable dictionaries and lists. This is not, in my opinion, one of them.

---

### Answer to the Actual Underlying Question

`Unhashable type` errors are usually thrown when you take a dictionary `A` and an unhashable object `B` and you try to use `B` as a key i.e. you call `A[B]`.

Your error comes simply from the fact that one of `name1`, `currentroom` or `itemdescription1` is a dictionary, and you tried to look up one of these in another dictionary.

Without the *full* code, we can't be certain which of these is the culprit, but you can rest assured that the error comes from there.

Comment: Most probably it is `itemdescription1`. As if it would have been `currentroom`, OP would have got error "unsupported operands dict and int" (for currentroom -1). And `name1` itself is a key in a dict (`thisitem`) so `itemdescription1` should be the culprit.